# Click an element based on attribute

Tags: xpath, click, css-selectors, casperjs

I have this code:

```
<div class="menuFamille" idcat="1025">
    <div class="menuFamilleButton   on ">item 1</div>
</div>

<div class="menuFamille" idcat="1026">
    <div class="menuFamilleButton   on ">item 2</div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to click on the first div with `idcat="1025"` in CasperJS. Should I use XPath?

Comment: yes I want to click on ".menuFamilleButton on" but with idcat="xxx", it's possible ? thank you

Comment: Yes I am a friend of Lalao ! you have a good memory !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an attribute selector (CSS). There is no need for an XPath expression, but I will add it for comparison:

```js
casper.click(".menuFamille[idcat='1025'] > .menuFamilleButton");
```

or

```js
casper.click(x("//*[contains(@class, 'menuFamille') and @idcat='1025']/*[contains(@class, 'menuFamilleButton')]"));
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your XPath expression I'd daresay. The `]` occurs too early - and something like `]/contains(` is not allowed.

Comment: Actually, there was another typo: `@idcat` - I've taken the liberty to edit.

Comment: @Mathias Thanks. Long time since I've written XPaths.

Comment: I used the first solution.